# Stanford CS231n: how to download the dataset (using .sh file in windows)?

Tags: download, sh

I am self-learning the convelutional neural network from the stanford cs231n course. I am trying to finish the [assignment1](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2016/assignment1/). However, I just got totally confused about how to download the data. I followed the instructor and see

> **Download data:** Once you have the starter code, you will need to
>   download the CIFAR-10 dataset. Run the following from the `assignment1`
>   directory:

```
cd cs231n/datasets
./get_datasets.sh
```

I don't understand what does it mean by *"run" the following*. Run what exactly? Previously, I use R so I understand what does "run R" means. But here it does not say run "what" or run the code in "where".

So I tried to run the code in *command prompt*, *Anaconda Prompt*, *PowerShell* or even *Git Bash*. The command prompt game error of `"." is not recognized as an internal or external command`. The *PowerShell* does not give error but does not give any result either. It just open a Text Document of code

```
# Get CIFAR10
wget http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
tar -xzvf cifar-10-python.tar.gz
rm cifar-10-python.tar.gz
```

The Git Bash gives me error of

```
get_datasets.sh: line 2: wget: command not found
tar (child): cifar-10-python.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rm: cannot remove 'cifar-10-python.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

How to download this data? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download [wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)
& copy wget.exe to your git

> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64

then restart the git bash or Navigate to your folder where get_datasets.sh file is present.
run the following command in git bash

> sh get_datasets.sh

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your folder where get_datasets.sh file is present using cmd.
Use the command **.\get_datasets.sh** in command prompt.

Make sure you are not missing wget. If wget is missing, install wget on your local machine and then run the shell script.

After installing wget properly use the instruction mentioned at the start.

Comment: Pay attention that a link can be broken. Instead, try to provide relative information in the answer